# Could not connect to SMTP host.Java mail Error

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I am trying to send a mail using java mail API.Here is my code

```
 public static void sendMail(MailObject mail) throws Exception
       {    

          String to = mail.toAdress;
          String from = mail.fromName;        
          String host = "mail.mycompanyname.com"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        //  String port="25";
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();        
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host); //$NON-NLS-1$
        // properties.setProperty()); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
          properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

           //  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            String add = mail.attachmentLocation;

             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setSubject(mail.subject);
              // create the message 
              MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

              //fill message to be sent
              messageBodyPart.setText(mail.message);

              Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
              multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

              //attach your file here
              messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

              DataSource source =  new FileDataSource(mail.attachmentLocation); // your file
              messageBodyPart.setDataHandler( new DataHandler(source));
              messageBodyPart.setFileName(mail.attachmentName);
              multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

              // Put message in parts
              message.setContent(multipart);

             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                      new InternetAddress(to));




             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully...."); //$NON-NLS-1$

       }
class MailObject
{
String toAdress;
String fromName;
String subject;
String message;
String attachmentLocation;
String attachmentName;
HTMLPage pageObject;
}
```

But i am getting Could not connect to smtp server error.Here is the full stack trace

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.mycompany.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.mycompanyname.com, port: 25
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at MailManager.sendMail(MailManager.java:68)
    at MailManager$1.widgetSelected(MailManager.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at MailManager.openMailDialogue(MailManager.java:165)
    at App2$2.widgetSelected(App2.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at App2.main(App2.java:521)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 23 more
```

i have tried to ping the server using telnet and it showed me the welcome screen.

Comment: Looks like a network problem. `Network is unreachable: connect`. Check if the mailserver is reachable from your network.

Comment: i pinged the server using telnet and it was working

Comment: Do you use port 25 with telnet?

Comment: yeah,i used port 25!

Comment: It seems very unlikely that running telnet on the same machine that your JavaMail program is running on would allow it to connect to port 25 on the same mail server, but your JavaMail program would get a network unreachable error.  Try running telnet and the [JavaMail msgsend sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) from a terminal window and copy&paste the results to show us.  If that doesn't work, check for a firewall or anti-virus program that might be blocking java but not telnet.